# php row data to another php page without form

Tags: php

I want to send row['id'] that comes from sql, to my other php page. How can I do that without use form?
I tried :

```
<a href="page2.php?($row['id'])=$id" class="style1">Hello</a>
```

And in page2 I have ;

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

but, it gives error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all I solved like that

```
<a href="page2.php?id='. urlencode($row['id']) .'" class="style1">Hello</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this, assuming you got HTML with embedded PHP:

```
<a href="page2.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($row['id']) ?>" class="style1">Hello</a>
```

or, assuming you use PHP to create HTML markup:

```
printf('<a href="page2.php?id=%s" class="style1">Hello</a>',
                   urlencode($row['id']));
```

Comment: I used it but I get error then I fixed it like that ;               <a href="profile.php?id='. urlencode($row['id']) .'" class="style1">' .$row['username']. '</a>

Comment: Updated my answer to cover both cases

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="page2.php?id=<?=$row['id']?>" class="style1">Hello</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="page2.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="style1">Hello</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="page2.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($row['id']) ?>" class="style1">Hello</a>
```

And later in page you want to get id, you just use $id = $_GET['id'];, or you can put it in session so you don't need to put it in url.